# Arduino Ethernet

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I want to send data collected by a sensor to a web server created by me with Java.

For example, I want to send a simple integer, `1` for example when the temperature of a sensor exceeds a threshold as the first test, but I can not know how. I managed to do otherwise, I mean make Arduino as a server, and from the browser by typing the IP address that I assigned to the board, to see those results, but what really interests me is to send the data instead of seeing them. How do I do that? What would a small example be?

I've tried the EthernetClient class, but I can not do what I want: (

Answer (score 1):

Just send a [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods). For example, `www.yourwebsite.com/arduinoreader.php?sensor=on`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good example on the Arduino website that shows exactly how to do this. Essentially you'll call `client.connect("www.xxx.xxx", 80)` where `client` is an object of the `EthernetClient` class, and then send a GET request using `client.println()`. You'll actually be sending the HTTP headers and data yourself, but this page shows you how to do it in the Code section: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient.

In that example you could replace the `client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.1");` with something like:

```
client.print("GET /api?temp=");
client.print(TEMP_VALUE);
client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
```